# Streaming using Qt

Tags: c++, qt, video-streaming

I wanted to make a simple media player using Qt that streams a video. The input (video) is coming from an IP Camera. How do I do this? I have checked the QMediaPlayer class, but I cannot figure out how to set the source to the ip address so that I can get the video from the link. What should I do?

Comment: What codec and protocol is the camera using?

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld n codec presently, its just a basic mjpg stream. I want to apply h264, but first I want to get the basic thing ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend embedding VLC, i've done this a few times and it works out really well.  Check out the project [here](https://github.com/ntadej/vlc-qt)

There is a sample project that is easy to follow included in the repo under examples/demo-player.

Comment: I am new to qt, so what procedure do I follow. Plus I am working on windows so please just give me the instructions and I will do the needful.

Comment: That repo contains a project that will compile under windows using QT.  You could modify it to do what you want.  The sample application includes a button that will allow you to open a URL and play it back.  Basically, open the project file in sample_project and compile/run.

Comment: See, that's the thing, it is not compiling and running. I'll post the errors ASAP

Comment: On running the app, that is I am trying to run the demo player example, it says that **video** is not a member of Ui::DemoPlayer. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What version of QT are you running?  You want to open and build the project "vlc-qt/examples/demo-player/demo-player.pro"